# I need to speed up my code, Also I need to use += i , for sure:for i in nums: sumof += i, its peivets memory block

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I try to convert my argmax into array.index(max(array))
I will appreciate any help.
I need to speed up my code.
This code is only for one picture, I will have around 20 pictures in a min. So that's why I try to make it faster as possible.

```
import time
import numpy as np

#tab = [0.061,0.001,0.022,0.002,0.015,0.021,0.066,0.005,0.053,0.018,0.011,0.024,0.052,0.021,0.077,0.010,0.045,0.017,0.016,0.007,0.071,0.167,0.052,0.016,0.017,0.004,0.009,0.014,0.001,0.059,0.018,0.008,0.004,0.009,0.009]#tabK = [0.009,0.003,0.002,0.001,0.157,0.003,0.067,0.005,0.006,0.002,0.012,0.005,0.033,0.002,0.007,0.010,0.001,0.008,0.037,0.008,0.377,0.011,0.043,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.013,0.016,0.004,0.005,0.057,0.013,0.023,0.026,0.018]CATEGORIES = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
#KOLEJNOSC ZNAKOW W TABLICY JEST ODWROCONA
CATEGORIES = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
"K","L","M","N","O","P","R","S","T","U",
"V","W","X","Y","Z"]



KR887JJ = [[0.002,0.006,0.004,0.045,0.002,0.017,0.006,0.077,0.001,0.035,0.042,0.005,0.004,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.058,0.352,0.002,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.007,0.007,0.007,0.004,0.005,0.009,0.089,0.036,0.053,0.041,0.004],[0.003,0.007,0.005,0.075,0.001,0.020,0.006,0.044,0.002,0.035,0.026,0.004,0.004,0.033,0.001,0.001,0.003,0.008,0.049,0.360,0.002,0.007,0.021,0.005,0.009,0.003,0.008,0.007,0.003,0.014,0.092,0.048,0.058,0.031,0.004],[0.002,0.000,0.025,0.012,0.006,0.002,0.001,0.627,0.006,0.021,0.022,0.008,0.004,0.006,0.004,0.033,0.000,0.006,0.011,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.009,0.000,0.002,0.040,0.007,0.005,0.015,0.000,0.035,0.001,0.008,0.015,0.053],[0.056,0.008,0.023,0.038,0.015,0.007,0.050,0.006,0.412,0.004,0.005,0.027,0.011,0.005,0.021,0.007,0.073,0.024,0.012,0.005,0.013,0.005,0.027,0.003,0.015,0.001,0.005,0.074,0.002,0.022,0.005,0.011,0.002,0.001,0.006],[0.025,0.011,0.025,0.034,0.018,0.027,0.090,0.008,0.258,0.006,0.007,0.026,0.016,0.008,0.026,0.011,0.079,0.030,0.026,0.008,0.018,0.011,0.033,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.106,0.004,0.021,0.012,0.013,0.003,0.005,0.014],[0.048,0.027,0.019,0.002,0.028,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.041,0.014,0.012,0.022,0.031,0.005,0.045,0.100,0.004,0.031,0.033,0.002,0.029,0.006,0.021,0.032,0.008,0.038,0.317,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.018,0.005,0.003,0.004,0.002],[0.013,0.002,0.002,0.000,0.164,0.001,0.060,0.004,0.006,0.002,0.018,0.003,0.035,0.002,0.008,0.008,0.001,0.008,0.028,0.005,0.383,0.013,0.063,0.010,0.004,0.002,0.014,0.016,0.002,0.005,0.048,0.011,0.028,0.017,0.012]]

[[0.004,0.007,0.005,0.042,0.002,0.014,0.011,0.054,0.002,0.032,0.051,0.005,0.005,0.044,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.008,0.056,0.389,0.003,0.008,0.023,0.005,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.006,0.004,0.010,0.070,0.029,0.049,0.031,0.005],[0.005,0.005,0.005,0.034,0.002,0.006,0.005,0.083,0.002,0.062,0.053,0.004,0.006,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.055,0.348,0.002,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.011,0.011,0.018,0.004,0.005,0.008,0.086,0.018,0.055,0.020,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.024,0.009,0.013,0.003,0.002,0.499,0.006,0.011,0.022,0.011,0.007,0.006,0.006,0.048,0.000,0.008,0.013,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.053,0.009,0.007,0.030,0.000,0.030,0.001,0.009,0.021,0.123],[0.039,0.008,0.029,0.041,0.013,0.008,0.054,0.005,0.369,0.004,0.005,0.023,0.011,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.100,0.022,0.012,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.028,0.002,0.015,0.000,0.003,0.102,0.001,0.021,0.006,0.012,0.002,0.002,0.007],[0.031,0.007,0.018,0.032,0.015,0.017,0.075,0.008,0.365,0.005,0.005,0.028,0.015,0.005,0.022,0.011,0.075,0.027,0.014,0.005,0.020,0.006,0.025,0.002,0.014,0.001,0.004,0.099,0.003,0.016,0.008,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.010],[0.046,0.022,0.022,0.002,0.031,0.003,0.008,0.022,0.047,0.011,0.010,0.039,0.035,0.005,0.048,0.110,0.002,0.028,0.031,0.003,0.029,0.006,0.016,0.022,0.007,0.059,0.289,0.005,0.016,0.003,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.004,0.003],[0.019,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.134,0.004,0.088,0.006,0.004,0.003,0.016,0.007,0.037,0.004,0.016,0.014,0.002,0.014,0.026,0.005,0.342,0.019,0.049,0.024,0.004,0.003,0.021,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.049,0.012,0.017,0.026,0.006]]

[[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.046,0.002,0.014,0.008,0.073,0.002,0.023,0.042,0.004,0.007,0.027,0.001,0.003,0.001,0.006,0.047,0.384,0.005,0.006,0.015,0.003,0.006,0.004,0.011,0.006,0.006,0.005,0.088,0.027,0.066,0.040,0.010],[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.039,0.002,0.009,0.005,0.089,0.001,0.036,0.043,0.004,0.006,0.026,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.006,0.051,0.387,0.003,0.005,0.014,0.003,0.007,0.007,0.014,0.004,0.007,0.005,0.090,0.022,0.064,0.030,0.006],[0.002,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.020,0.005,0.004,0.282,0.005,0.012,0.022,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.000,0.017,0.030,0.019,0.009,0.003,0.009,0.000,0.004,0.053,0.010,0.016,0.049,0.000,0.043,0.002,0.017,0.037,0.224],[0.028,0.015,0.029,0.039,0.023,0.020,0.097,0.008,0.239,0.004,0.009,0.021,0.019,0.008,0.017,0.008,0.082,0.023,0.025,0.012,0.020,0.010,0.037,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.110,0.003,0.019,0.012,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.015],[0.037,0.013,0.035,0.053,0.025,0.022,0.057,0.017,0.250,0.005,0.009,0.037,0.025,0.008,0.029,0.013,0.057,0.029,0.029,0.009,0.015,0.009,0.027,0.002,0.020,0.002,0.006,0.092,0.006,0.012,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.004,0.021],[0.036,0.022,0.024,0.003,0.022,0.004,0.011,0.019,0.069,0.014,0.011,0.035,0.045,0.006,0.057,0.096,0.004,0.037,0.030,0.004,0.039,0.007,0.021,0.018,0.010,0.031,0.256,0.013,0.018,0.003,0.018,0.005,0.004,0.006,0.004],[0.015,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.174,0.004,0.085,0.008,0.005,0.002,0.015,0.008,0.028,0.003,0.013,0.016,0.001,0.015,0.029,0.004,0.357,0.013,0.043,0.017,0.003,0.003,0.017,0.010,0.004,0.007,0.037,0.013,0.015,0.020,0.010]]

[[0.005,0.006,0.006,0.055,0.002,0.017,0.009,0.076,0.003,0.035,0.032,0.007,0.005,0.050,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.011,0.050,0.391,0.002,0.005,0.018,0.003,0.012,0.009,0.009,0.005,0.005,0.012,0.068,0.032,0.032,0.017,0.006],[0.009,0.005,0.007,0.064,0.002,0.022,0.009,0.040,0.003,0.030,0.026,0.010,0.006,0.069,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.011,0.040,0.379,0.002,0.009,0.021,0.005,0.017,0.007,0.009,0.005,0.003,0.034,0.063,0.035,0.029,0.017,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.011,0.004,0.003,0.458,0.004,0.012,0.023,0.010,0.007,0.009,0.006,0.039,0.000,0.012,0.016,0.014,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.052,0.008,0.009,0.039,0.000,0.036,0.001,0.013,0.032,0.139],[0.042,0.012,0.023,0.029,0.043,0.015,0.111,0.010,0.235,0.004,0.009,0.036,0.023,0.010,0.018,0.010,0.039,0.029,0.024,0.012,0.025,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.019,0.002,0.005,0.084,0.004,0.018,0.013,0.012,0.004,0.005,0.023],[0.030,0.008,0.017,0.033,0.011,0.020,0.103,0.009,0.289,0.004,0.006,0.030,0.022,0.007,0.021,0.011,0.108,0.031,0.013,0.008,0.020,0.006,0.023,0.002,0.018,0.001,0.004,0.102,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.007,0.002,0.003,0.009],[0.034,0.024,0.018,0.003,0.025,0.005,0.008,0.025,0.053,0.010,0.008,0.045,0.036,0.006,0.050,0.119,0.002,0.035,0.028,0.003,0.029,0.005,0.014,0.017,0.007,0.060,0.275,0.006,0.019,0.002,0.013,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.005],[0.016,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.130,0.003,0.080,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.017,0.005,0.038,0.002,0.015,0.014,0.002,0.011,0.027,0.004,0.378,0.016,0.051,0.019,0.004,0.002,0.020,0.012,0.004,0.006,0.040,0.013,0.023,0.020,0.008]]

[[0.006,0.004,0.007,0.052,0.002,0.012,0.005,0.066,0.002,0.043,0.036,0.007,0.007,0.051,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.037,0.401,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.013,0.010,0.014,0.004,0.004,0.016,0.077,0.021,0.038,0.018,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.012,0.008,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.462,0.004,0.011,0.022,0.008,0.006,0.006,0.006,0.052,0.000,0.012,0.018,0.012,0.005,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.046,0.009,0.009,0.040,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.012,0.031,0.136],[0.004,0.003,0.007,0.042,0.001,0.008,0.005,0.060,0.002,0.062,0.050,0.005,0.004,0.053,0.000,0.001,0.002,0.006,0.033,0.422,0.001,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.011,0.007,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.013,0.065,0.024,0.045,0.017,0.003],[0.029,0.015,0.032,0.058,0.018,0.013,0.067,0.012,0.287,0.006,0.010,0.025,0.016,0.007,0.017,0.009,0.059,0.023,0.026,0.011,0.016,0.006,0.033,0.003,0.017,0.001,0.006,0.118,0.004,0.014,0.009,0.012,0.004,0.003,0.012],[0.056,0.011,0.024,0.034,0.027,0.015,0.065,0.013,0.271,0.006,0.007,0.062,0.028,0.013,0.026,0.014,0.030,0.039,0.027,0.011,0.019,0.006,0.031,0.003,0.027,0.005,0.009,0.061,0.006,0.014,0.011,0.006,0.002,0.004,0.016],[0.041,0.020,0.022,0.002,0.019,0.004,0.007,0.024,0.046,0.016,0.008,0.051,0.036,0.006,0.051,0.109,0.002,0.030,0.027,0.003,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.017,0.008,0.067,0.286,0.005,0.015,0.003,0.014,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.014,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.106,0.007,0.079,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.010,0.041,0.004,0.013,0.011,0.001,0.014,0.031,0.007,0.377,0.022,0.049,0.017,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.009,0.004,0.009,0.050,0.013,0.016,0.034,0.008]]

[[0.008,0.004,0.008,0.064,0.001,0.018,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.043,0.035,0.008,0.005,0.076,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.009,0.037,0.382,0.001,0.011,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.006,0.007,0.005,0.002,0.030,0.057,0.031,0.029,0.017,0.004],[0.002,0.004,0.004,0.044,0.001,0.012,0.005,0.068,0.001,0.043,0.052,0.003,0.005,0.030,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.007,0.041,0.350,0.003,0.007,0.019,0.005,0.007,0.004,0.011,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.099,0.035,0.076,0.038,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.015,0.011,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.517,0.004,0.012,0.028,0.007,0.005,0.007,0.005,0.035,0.000,0.011,0.014,0.012,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.000,0.002,0.030,0.006,0.009,0.029,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.016,0.034,0.114],[0.026,0.010,0.036,0.064,0.011,0.009,0.052,0.010,0.360,0.004,0.007,0.022,0.015,0.005,0.017,0.006,0.067,0.019,0.017,0.008,0.013,0.006,0.026,0.002,0.015,0.001,0.004,0.121,0.003,0.011,0.006,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.011],[0.044,0.017,0.027,0.037,0.024,0.016,0.079,0.010,0.259,0.006,0.009,0.032,0.023,0.009,0.022,0.012,0.064,0.031,0.026,0.010,0.019,0.007,0.034,0.004,0.021,0.002,0.007,0.086,0.005,0.018,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.003,0.011],[0.033,0.013,0.021,0.002,0.014,0.003,0.006,0.023,0.033,0.015,0.009,0.048,0.040,0.007,0.056,0.098,0.002,0.032,0.023,0.003,0.023,0.006,0.013,0.015,0.009,0.069,0.331,0.005,0.018,0.002,0.012,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.017,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.096,0.008,0.095,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.013,0.012,0.045,0.006,0.017,0.013,0.002,0.016,0.029,0.007,0.360,0.023,0.045,0.023,0.005,0.004,0.018,0.008,0.005,0.010,0.042,0.011,0.013,0.032,0.007]]

[[0.007,0.004,0.007,0.082,0.002,0.023,0.009,0.029,0.003,0.024,0.024,0.008,0.006,0.062,0.001,0.001,0.005,0.009,0.032,0.391,0.002,0.012,0.020,0.005,0.016,0.004,0.006,0.006,0.002,0.037,0.061,0.041,0.033,0.019,0.006],[0.004,0.004,0.008,0.078,0.001,0.013,0.005,0.059,0.002,0.044,0.041,0.006,0.005,0.052,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.036,0.366,0.001,0.010,0.015,0.003,0.011,0.008,0.008,0.005,0.004,0.015,0.074,0.035,0.045,0.023,0.007],[0.001,0.001,0.013,0.010,0.015,0.006,0.004,0.299,0.004,0.011,0.021,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.009,0.044,0.000,0.021,0.023,0.017,0.008,0.004,0.007,0.000,0.003,0.056,0.008,0.014,0.056,0.000,0.040,0.002,0.016,0.039,0.217],[0.021,0.011,0.022,0.060,0.018,0.026,0.090,0.014,0.234,0.005,0.011,0.025,0.016,0.009,0.015,0.011,0.052,0.030,0.029,0.015,0.019,0.007,0.030,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.134,0.006,0.013,0.011,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.020],[0.031,0.012,0.027,0.036,0.023,0.020,0.053,0.018,0.269,0.006,0.008,0.029,0.036,0.007,0.029,0.021,0.046,0.030,0.028,0.009,0.023,0.007,0.027,0.003,0.020,0.002,0.010,0.098,0.010,0.009,0.016,0.009,0.004,0.005,0.018],[0.036,0.019,0.017,0.002,0.027,0.004,0.009,0.027,0.063,0.012,0.008,0.045,0.035,0.006,0.050,0.140,0.002,0.036,0.030,0.003,0.031,0.004,0.017,0.016,0.007,0.055,0.239,0.007,0.018,0.002,0.014,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.004],[0.018,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.186,0.004,0.107,0.005,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.004,0.017,0.018,0.001,0.012,0.034,0.004,0.300,0.014,0.036,0.018,0.004,0.004,0.020,0.010,0.005,0.008,0.049,0.009,0.011,0.020,0.008]]

start = time.time()

for sing in KR887JJ: 
    print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(sing)])

    #print(CATEGORIES[sing.index(max(sing))])




def list_mean(nums):
    sumof = 0
    num_of = len(nums)
    mean = 0
    for i in nums:
        sumof += i 
    mean = sumof / num_of
    return float(mean)


end = time.time()

print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
```

Also I 100% need this part, for I in nums:
sumof += i. Iteration like this will not take a lot of memory because it counts constantly not ones with big blocked memory peace.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you working with numpy arrays? Why do you think `array.index(max(array))` would be faster? That would mean you are using a `list`?

Comment: It is very helpful if you provide *real example data*, with a complete description fo what you code is supposed to do, including corresponding outputs for your inputs

Comment: `numpy` arrays do not have an `index` method.  Your variable names and question should reflect that difference.  e.g. `alist.index....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.argmax isn't slower than array.index(np.max(array)), but the list_mean can be much more efficient: if you want a full python implementation, you can use

```
sum(nums)/len(nums)
```

Or even more efficient :

```
np.mean(nums)
```

(you already work with arrays)

Comment: Sorry, my code works faster, but I really need to speed it up.

Comment: and I do iteration, becouse it take less space: for i in nums:
   sumof += i. As u see I have a lot of data

Comment: Could you show a more complete code ? In fact It is hard to understand what your code does, the context etc... One sure thing is that the optimisation problem doesn't come from the argmax, it might be larger.

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't have that much data ..

Answer (score 0):

MORE OR LESS:
import time
import numpy as np

#KOLEJNOSC ZNAKOW W TABLICY JEST ODWROCONA
CATEGORIES = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

KR887JJ = [[0.002,0.006,0.004,0.045,0.002,0.017,0.006,0.077,0.001,0.035,0.042,0.005,0.004,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.058,0.352,0.002,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.007,0.007,0.007,0.004,0.005,0.009,0.089,0.036,0.053,0.041,0.004],[0.003,0.007,0.005,0.075,0.001,0.020,0.006,0.044,0.002,0.035,0.026,0.004,0.004,0.033,0.001,0.001,0.003,0.008,0.049,0.360,0.002,0.007,0.021,0.005,0.009,0.003,0.008,0.007,0.003,0.014,0.092,0.048,0.058,0.031,0.004],[0.002,0.000,0.025,0.012,0.006,0.002,0.001,0.627,0.006,0.021,0.022,0.008,0.004,0.006,0.004,0.033,0.000,0.006,0.011,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.009,0.000,0.002,0.040,0.007,0.005,0.015,0.000,0.035,0.001,0.008,0.015,0.053],[0.056,0.008,0.023,0.038,0.015,0.007,0.050,0.006,0.412,0.004,0.005,0.027,0.011,0.005,0.021,0.007,0.073,0.024,0.012,0.005,0.013,0.005,0.027,0.003,0.015,0.001,0.005,0.074,0.002,0.022,0.005,0.011,0.002,0.001,0.006],[0.025,0.011,0.025,0.034,0.018,0.027,0.090,0.008,0.258,0.006,0.007,0.026,0.016,0.008,0.026,0.011,0.079,0.030,0.026,0.008,0.018,0.011,0.033,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.106,0.004,0.021,0.012,0.013,0.003,0.005,0.014],[0.048,0.027,0.019,0.002,0.028,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.041,0.014,0.012,0.022,0.031,0.005,0.045,0.100,0.004,0.031,0.033,0.002,0.029,0.006,0.021,0.032,0.008,0.038,0.317,0.007,0.017,0.004,0.018,0.005,0.003,0.004,0.002],[0.013,0.002,0.002,0.000,0.164,0.001,0.060,0.004,0.006,0.002,0.018,0.003,0.035,0.002,0.008,0.008,0.001,0.008,0.028,0.005,0.383,0.013,0.063,0.010,0.004,0.002,0.014,0.016,0.002,0.005,0.048,0.011,0.028,0.017,0.012]]
[[0.004,0.007,0.005,0.042,0.002,0.014,0.011,0.054,0.002,0.032,0.051,0.005,0.005,0.044,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.008,0.056,0.389,0.003,0.008,0.023,0.005,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.006,0.004,0.010,0.070,0.029,0.049,0.031,0.005],[0.005,0.005,0.005,0.034,0.002,0.006,0.005,0.083,0.002,0.062,0.053,0.004,0.006,0.039,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.008,0.055,0.348,0.002,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.011,0.011,0.018,0.004,0.005,0.008,0.086,0.018,0.055,0.020,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.024,0.009,0.013,0.003,0.002,0.499,0.006,0.011,0.022,0.011,0.007,0.006,0.006,0.048,0.000,0.008,0.013,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.053,0.009,0.007,0.030,0.000,0.030,0.001,0.009,0.021,0.123],[0.039,0.008,0.029,0.041,0.013,0.008,0.054,0.005,0.369,0.004,0.005,0.023,0.011,0.005,0.020,0.005,0.100,0.022,0.012,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.028,0.002,0.015,0.000,0.003,0.102,0.001,0.021,0.006,0.012,0.002,0.002,0.007],[0.031,0.007,0.018,0.032,0.015,0.017,0.075,0.008,0.365,0.005,0.005,0.028,0.015,0.005,0.022,0.011,0.075,0.027,0.014,0.005,0.020,0.006,0.025,0.002,0.014,0.001,0.004,0.099,0.003,0.016,0.008,0.009,0.002,0.002,0.010],[0.046,0.022,0.022,0.002,0.031,0.003,0.008,0.022,0.047,0.011,0.010,0.039,0.035,0.005,0.048,0.110,0.002,0.028,0.031,0.003,0.029,0.006,0.016,0.022,0.007,0.059,0.289,0.005,0.016,0.003,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.004,0.003],[0.019,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.134,0.004,0.088,0.006,0.004,0.003,0.016,0.007,0.037,0.004,0.016,0.014,0.002,0.014,0.026,0.005,0.342,0.019,0.049,0.024,0.004,0.003,0.021,0.009,0.005,0.009,0.049,0.012,0.017,0.026,0.006]]
[[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.046,0.002,0.014,0.008,0.073,0.002,0.023,0.042,0.004,0.007,0.027,0.001,0.003,0.001,0.006,0.047,0.384,0.005,0.006,0.015,0.003,0.006,0.004,0.011,0.006,0.006,0.005,0.088,0.027,0.066,0.040,0.010],[0.002,0.005,0.005,0.039,0.002,0.009,0.005,0.089,0.001,0.036,0.043,0.004,0.006,0.026,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.006,0.051,0.387,0.003,0.005,0.014,0.003,0.007,0.007,0.014,0.004,0.007,0.005,0.090,0.022,0.064,0.030,0.006],[0.002,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.020,0.005,0.004,0.282,0.005,0.012,0.022,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.000,0.017,0.030,0.019,0.009,0.003,0.009,0.000,0.004,0.053,0.010,0.016,0.049,0.000,0.043,0.002,0.017,0.037,0.224],[0.028,0.015,0.029,0.039,0.023,0.020,0.097,0.008,0.239,0.004,0.009,0.021,0.019,0.008,0.017,0.008,0.082,0.023,0.025,0.012,0.020,0.010,0.037,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.110,0.003,0.019,0.012,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.015],[0.037,0.013,0.035,0.053,0.025,0.022,0.057,0.017,0.250,0.005,0.009,0.037,0.025,0.008,0.029,0.013,0.057,0.029,0.029,0.009,0.015,0.009,0.027,0.002,0.020,0.002,0.006,0.092,0.006,0.012,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.004,0.021],[0.036,0.022,0.024,0.003,0.022,0.004,0.011,0.019,0.069,0.014,0.011,0.035,0.045,0.006,0.057,0.096,0.004,0.037,0.030,0.004,0.039,0.007,0.021,0.018,0.010,0.031,0.256,0.013,0.018,0.003,0.018,0.005,0.004,0.006,0.004],[0.015,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.174,0.004,0.085,0.008,0.005,0.002,0.015,0.008,0.028,0.003,0.013,0.016,0.001,0.015,0.029,0.004,0.357,0.013,0.043,0.017,0.003,0.003,0.017,0.010,0.004,0.007,0.037,0.013,0.015,0.020,0.010]]
[[0.005,0.006,0.006,0.055,0.002,0.017,0.009,0.076,0.003,0.035,0.032,0.007,0.005,0.050,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.011,0.050,0.391,0.002,0.005,0.018,0.003,0.012,0.009,0.009,0.005,0.005,0.012,0.068,0.032,0.032,0.017,0.006],[0.009,0.005,0.007,0.064,0.002,0.022,0.009,0.040,0.003,0.030,0.026,0.010,0.006,0.069,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.011,0.040,0.379,0.002,0.009,0.021,0.005,0.017,0.007,0.009,0.005,0.003,0.034,0.063,0.035,0.029,0.017,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.014,0.011,0.011,0.004,0.003,0.458,0.004,0.012,0.023,0.010,0.007,0.009,0.006,0.039,0.000,0.012,0.016,0.014,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.052,0.008,0.009,0.039,0.000,0.036,0.001,0.013,0.032,0.139],[0.042,0.012,0.023,0.029,0.043,0.015,0.111,0.010,0.235,0.004,0.009,0.036,0.023,0.010,0.018,0.010,0.039,0.029,0.024,0.012,0.025,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.019,0.002,0.005,0.084,0.004,0.018,0.013,0.012,0.004,0.005,0.023],[0.030,0.008,0.017,0.033,0.011,0.020,0.103,0.009,0.289,0.004,0.006,0.030,0.022,0.007,0.021,0.011,0.108,0.031,0.013,0.008,0.020,0.006,0.023,0.002,0.018,0.001,0.004,0.102,0.005,0.012,0.007,0.007,0.002,0.003,0.009],[0.034,0.024,0.018,0.003,0.025,0.005,0.008,0.025,0.053,0.010,0.008,0.045,0.036,0.006,0.050,0.119,0.002,0.035,0.028,0.003,0.029,0.005,0.014,0.017,0.007,0.060,0.275,0.006,0.019,0.002,0.013,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.005],[0.016,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.130,0.003,0.080,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.017,0.005,0.038,0.002,0.015,0.014,0.002,0.011,0.027,0.004,0.378,0.016,0.051,0.019,0.004,0.002,0.020,0.012,0.004,0.006,0.040,0.013,0.023,0.020,0.008]]
[[0.006,0.004,0.007,0.052,0.002,0.012,0.005,0.066,0.002,0.043,0.036,0.007,0.007,0.051,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.037,0.401,0.002,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.013,0.010,0.014,0.004,0.004,0.016,0.077,0.021,0.038,0.018,0.006],[0.001,0.001,0.012,0.008,0.013,0.004,0.002,0.462,0.004,0.011,0.022,0.008,0.006,0.006,0.006,0.052,0.000,0.012,0.018,0.012,0.005,0.002,0.007,0.000,0.002,0.046,0.009,0.009,0.040,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.012,0.031,0.136],[0.004,0.003,0.007,0.042,0.001,0.008,0.005,0.060,0.002,0.062,0.050,0.005,0.004,0.053,0.000,0.001,0.002,0.006,0.033,0.422,0.001,0.008,0.017,0.004,0.011,0.007,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.013,0.065,0.024,0.045,0.017,0.003],[0.029,0.015,0.032,0.058,0.018,0.013,0.067,0.012,0.287,0.006,0.010,0.025,0.016,0.007,0.017,0.009,0.059,0.023,0.026,0.011,0.016,0.006,0.033,0.003,0.017,0.001,0.006,0.118,0.004,0.014,0.009,0.012,0.004,0.003,0.012],[0.056,0.011,0.024,0.034,0.027,0.015,0.065,0.013,0.271,0.006,0.007,0.062,0.028,0.013,0.026,0.014,0.030,0.039,0.027,0.011,0.019,0.006,0.031,0.003,0.027,0.005,0.009,0.061,0.006,0.014,0.011,0.006,0.002,0.004,0.016],[0.041,0.020,0.022,0.002,0.019,0.004,0.007,0.024,0.046,0.016,0.008,0.051,0.036,0.006,0.051,0.109,0.002,0.030,0.027,0.003,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.017,0.008,0.067,0.286,0.005,0.015,0.003,0.014,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.014,0.003,0.002,0.000,0.106,0.007,0.079,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.010,0.041,0.004,0.013,0.011,0.001,0.014,0.031,0.007,0.377,0.022,0.049,0.017,0.004,0.003,0.014,0.009,0.004,0.009,0.050,0.013,0.016,0.034,0.008]]
[[0.008,0.004,0.008,0.064,0.001,0.018,0.009,0.041,0.003,0.043,0.035,0.008,0.005,0.076,0.001,0.001,0.004,0.009,0.037,0.382,0.001,0.011,0.024,0.005,0.015,0.006,0.007,0.005,0.002,0.030,0.057,0.031,0.029,0.017,0.004],[0.002,0.004,0.004,0.044,0.001,0.012,0.005,0.068,0.001,0.043,0.052,0.003,0.005,0.030,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.007,0.041,0.350,0.003,0.007,0.019,0.005,0.007,0.004,0.011,0.005,0.003,0.007,0.099,0.035,0.076,0.038,0.004],[0.001,0.001,0.015,0.011,0.009,0.004,0.002,0.517,0.004,0.012,0.028,0.007,0.005,0.007,0.005,0.035,0.000,0.011,0.014,0.012,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.000,0.002,0.030,0.006,0.009,0.029,0.000,0.039,0.002,0.016,0.034,0.114],[0.026,0.010,0.036,0.064,0.011,0.009,0.052,0.010,0.360,0.004,0.007,0.022,0.015,0.005,0.017,0.006,0.067,0.019,0.017,0.008,0.013,0.006,0.026,0.002,0.015,0.001,0.004,0.121,0.003,0.011,0.006,0.010,0.003,0.002,0.011],[0.044,0.017,0.027,0.037,0.024,0.016,0.079,0.010,0.259,0.006,0.009,0.032,0.023,0.009,0.022,0.012,0.064,0.031,0.026,0.010,0.019,0.007,0.034,0.004,0.021,0.002,0.007,0.086,0.005,0.018,0.011,0.011,0.003,0.003,0.011],[0.033,0.013,0.021,0.002,0.014,0.003,0.006,0.023,0.033,0.015,0.009,0.048,0.040,0.007,0.056,0.098,0.002,0.032,0.023,0.003,0.023,0.006,0.013,0.015,0.009,0.069,0.331,0.005,0.018,0.002,0.012,0.003,0.002,0.005,0.003],[0.017,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.096,0.008,0.095,0.007,0.004,0.003,0.013,0.012,0.045,0.006,0.017,0.013,0.002,0.016,0.029,0.007,0.360,0.023,0.045,0.023,0.005,0.004,0.018,0.008,0.005,0.010,0.042,0.011,0.013,0.032,0.007]]
[[0.007,0.004,0.007,0.082,0.002,0.023,0.009,0.029,0.003,0.024,0.024,0.008,0.006,0.062,0.001,0.001,0.005,0.009,0.032,0.391,0.002,0.012,0.020,0.005,0.016,0.004,0.006,0.006,0.002,0.037,0.061,0.041,0.033,0.019,0.006],[0.004,0.004,0.008,0.078,0.001,0.013,0.005,0.059,0.002,0.044,0.041,0.006,0.005,0.052,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.008,0.036,0.366,0.001,0.010,0.015,0.003,0.011,0.008,0.008,0.005,0.004,0.015,0.074,0.035,0.045,0.023,0.007],[0.001,0.001,0.013,0.010,0.015,0.006,0.004,0.299,0.004,0.011,0.021,0.011,0.009,0.010,0.009,0.044,0.000,0.021,0.023,0.017,0.008,0.004,0.007,0.000,0.003,0.056,0.008,0.014,0.056,0.000,0.040,0.002,0.016,0.039,0.217],[0.021,0.011,0.022,0.060,0.018,0.026,0.090,0.014,0.234,0.005,0.011,0.025,0.016,0.009,0.015,0.011,0.052,0.030,0.029,0.015,0.019,0.007,0.030,0.003,0.016,0.001,0.003,0.134,0.006,0.013,0.011,0.014,0.004,0.005,0.020],[0.031,0.012,0.027,0.036,0.023,0.020,0.053,0.018,0.269,0.006,0.008,0.029,0.036,0.007,0.029,0.021,0.046,0.030,0.028,0.009,0.023,0.007,0.027,0.003,0.020,0.002,0.010,0.098,0.010,0.009,0.016,0.009,0.004,0.005,0.018],[0.036,0.019,0.017,0.002,0.027,0.004,0.009,0.027,0.063,0.012,0.008,0.045,0.035,0.006,0.050,0.140,0.002,0.036,0.030,0.003,0.031,0.004,0.017,0.016,0.007,0.055,0.239,0.007,0.018,0.002,0.014,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.004],[0.018,0.004,0.002,0.000,0.186,0.004,0.107,0.005,0.005,0.003,0.010,0.008,0.041,0.004,0.017,0.018,0.001,0.012,0.034,0.004,0.300,0.014,0.036,0.018,0.004,0.004,0.020,0.010,0.005,0.008,0.049,0.009,0.011,0.020,0.008]]

start = time.time()

for sing in KR887JJ:
print(CATEGORIES[sing.index(max(sing))])

def list_mean(nums):

```
sumof, len = 0, 0
for i in nums:      
    sumof += i
#len += 1
return sumof / len
```

end = time.time()

print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")